# Plot displays additional line that is not included in data

Tags: matlab, plot

I would be glad if you help me. I wrote short MATLAB program that only displays measured values from a .csv file. It usually works, but with one dataset it draws one extra line for each data intput. But the extra line is not included in data. Can you help?

Code:

```
Array=dlmread('file adress'); %Data opening
col1 = Array(:, 1); 
col2 = Array(:, 6);
col3 = Array(:, 7);
col4 = Array(:, 8);
col5 = Array(:, 9);

plot(col1, col2)%, col1, col3, col1, col4, col1, col5);
legend('Position Ra1 X axis positive','Position Ra1 X axis negative','Position Ra1 Y axis positive','Position Ra1 Y axis negative')
%axis([0 25001 1100 1850]);
xlabel('Samples');
ylabel('Position measurements [um]');
title('Radial bearing 1 position measurement - shaft rotates')
```

And result is here

[image: result]

Thank you a lot!

Comment: It looks like the data contains one unwanted value at the beginning or at the end. Maybe check first / last rows of the `.csv` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here appears to be a point `(0,0)` at the end of your dataset, so MATLAB connects the last correct point with `(0,0)` in the plot. As the data is stored column-wise in the file, this means that you have an empty row / a row of zeros in the `.csv` file.

The savest solution would be to check how you generate the `.csv` files and make sure that no extra rows are generated. If that is not possible, or your MATLAB script has to be able to handle such extra rows, then you can check if the last row contains only zeros by taking the sum over all (absolute) values of the last row and checking if that is zero:

```
deleteLastRow = sum(abs(Array(end,:))) == 0;
```

Now you can delete the last row if this expression is true

```
if deleteLastRow
    Array(end,:) = [];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

I did not find any [0,0] point (probably it read empty line). I just copied the data to new file and it works now.